# How can resolve this error in Python: "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable"

Tags: python

How can I fix this error?

I'm facing this error on every example I'm trying to run. I'm new to Python and trying to add spaces in my code.

This is my code

```
spaces = '' * 12
print('add some spaces in this text' % spaces)
```

And I'm getting this error

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: I'm getting this error

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-0d528f4918ac> in <module>
      1 spaces= '' * 12
----> 2 print( 'add some spaces in this text' % spaces)

TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: because there's no space in the string you're multiplying. and there's no placeholder in the string you're inserting the spaces into. `spaces = ' ' * 12` and then `'add some spaces in %s this text' % spaces` (put the `%s` where you want the spaces to go).

Comment: Please click `Edit` and add your error into the text of your question, there's no reason to put it in a comment.

Comment: You can [edit] your question at any time, to fix mistakes, add clarification, etc rather than adding followup comments. Most importantly, **do not post entire blocks of code/errors in the comments** -- it can't be read or understood easily. It needs to be [correctly formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fix

```
spaces= ' ' * 12
print('add some spaces in this text'.replace(' ', spaces))
```

output

```
add            some            spaces            in            this            text
```

Answer (score 3):

It should be

```
spaces = ' ' * 12
print('Add some spaces in this text:' + spaces + 'That was some spaces!')
```

Answer (score 2):

I would make use of f-string literals here:

```
spaces = ' ' * 12
print(f'Add some spaces in this text: {spaces} That was some spaces!')
```

Comment: what is meant by f

Comment: I'm getting the same error while trying your code.

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: Old python syntax for printing variable in code used to involve the ```format``` method, but the f here was developed to replace it. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/formatted-string-literals-f-strings-python/

If you are still getting error, you must make sure that you are using ```spaces = ' ' * 12``` instead of ```spaces = '' * 12```